# In PyQt QTableView - How to set font to a cell or column?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, pyqt6

I'm using **Python + PyQt** to display a simple grid with read-only text, using **QTableView**.

How can I set a font to certain column(s), or individual cells ("items") ?

If it was a **QTableWidget**, I'd create `item= TableWidgetItem; item.setFont(...); table.setItem(row, col, item)`. But I can't find an equivalent for **QTableView**.

I can't find similar mechanism in QTableViue; I can't figure whether (or how, or why) I'd need to write a delegate subclass, and what to do with it.

There's a similar question for QT+C++, which seems irrelevant.

Thanks!

Comment: These aspects are normally set on the model. What model are you using? If it's a QStandardItemModel, then just use [`setFont()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setFont) on the required items. If you're using a custom model, just return an appropriate font from the `data()` function with the `Qt.FontRole` role.